# Prove/Disprove linear independence of differential system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let y1, y2, ..., yn be differentiable (real-valued) solutions of the following
system of differential equations

$$\frac{dy_1}{dt}=a_{11}y_1 + · · · + a_{1n}y_n,$$
$$\frac{dy_2}{dt}=a_{21}y_1 + · · · + a_{2n}y_n,$$
$$· · ·$$
$$\frac{dy_n}{dt}=a_{n1}y_1 + · · · + a_{nn}y_n,$$
for some constant $\ a_{ij} > 0$. Suppose that
$$y_i(t) \rightarrow  0, $$
as $ t \rightarrow \infty$, $\forall i=1,...,n.$ Are the functions $y_1,y_2,...y_n$ necessarily linearly dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a system $y'=Ay$, $A=((a_{ij}))_{i,j=1..n}$. Its general solution theory follows from diagonalizing the matrix $A$. It gives the general solution form in the case that all eigenvalues are simple as
$$
y(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n c_ke^{\lambda_kt}v_k
$$
with eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ and eigenvectors $v_k$.

The real parts of the eigenvalues sum up to the trace of the system matrix, 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nRe(λ_k)=tr(A)=\sum_{i=1}^na_{ii}.
$$
 By assumption, that trace is positive. At least one eigenvalue, say $λ_1$ has a positive real part. The exponential for that is exponentially growing, unbounded.

If you exclude this component $c_1e^{λ_1t}v_1$ by demanding $c_1=0$, then you have to construct the solution from a generating system with less than $n$ elements, ...

Comment: What do you create the system matrix out of, and how do the derivatives relate back to the original functions?

Comment: The only thing I still don't under stand is how you can set $c_1$ to 0 seemingly arbitrarily and why we can assume the trace is positive.

Comment: Your assumption is that all the $a_{ij}$ are positive. If $c_1\ne 0$, then at least one function will grow exponentially.